# How to customize clear button in ng-select?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

The Ng-select component has a clear button. Is there a way to use an SVG image instead of default 'x' character?

Screenshot : 
[image: http://joxi.ru/Q2KX44VTwWdB0A]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found another way of doing this, but in CSS. You can add class 'custom' to ng-select and change its styling like this:

```html
<ng-select class="custom"></ng-select>
```

```css
/* Hide default cross */
.ng-select.custom .ng-clear-wrapper .ng-clear {
  font-size: 0;
}

/* Display our image */
.ng-select.custom .ng-clear-wrapper .ng-clear::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: url('path/to/svg');
}
```

P.S: if you're using view encapsulation, your styles won't be applied to ng-select. To avoid this, add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to component metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not available yet in [**ng-select**](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#) docs.

But you can force change it manually with another **icon** after the **ng-select** rendered.

**Typescript** Example :

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('ngSelect', { static: false }) public ngSelect: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        (this.ngSelect as any).element.querySelector('.ng-clear').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-code"></i>';
      }, 1);
    }
}
```

don't forget to add `#ngSelect` to ng-select Element :

**HTML** Example :

```
<ng-select #ngSelect>
</ng-select>
```